# Bash. Скрипт для получения общего количества принятых и отправленных байт по сети

Tags: linux, bash, freebsd

Нужно написать скрипт который будет получать общее количество (принятых|переданных) байт по сети и записывать строку в файл.

**ФОРМАТ ФАЙЛА**

<Текущее время и дата> <Количество принятых байт> <Количество отправленных байт>
<Текущее время и дата> <Количество принятых байт> <Количество отправленных байт>

...

Comment: нужно написать - напишите. или укажите в вопросе что именно вызвало у вас сложности в решении задачи. В linux количество байт можно получить например в /proc/net/dev. или с помощью ifconfig. только надо решить сначала, что такое "сеть". что если у вас в машине несколько устройств для работы с сетями  и по каким из них собственно нужна информация

Comment: почитайте https://www.lissyara.su/articles/freebsd/traffic_count/ и https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/31010/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый вечер,

Вы можете считать данные напрямую из файла /sys/class/INTERFACE/statistics/tx_bytes,rx_bytes, но проблема в том, что это данные только от момента запуска системы.

Пример скрипта без особых зависимостей, который собирает данные от каждого интерфейса (в вопросе не уточнено, нужно ли учитывать все интерфейсы доступные системе).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Rx  received (download)
# Tx  transmitted (upload)
main()
{
    interfaces="$(ls /sys/class/net -I "lo" -I "vir*")"
    for i in $interfaces; do
        tx_bytes="$(</sys/class/net/"$i"/statistics/tx_bytes)"
        rx_bytes="$(</sys/class/net/"$i"/statistics/rx_bytes)"
        printf "<%s><%s><%s><%s>\n" "$(date)" "$i" "$rx_bytes" "$tx_bytes" 
    done
}
main "$@" >> /path/to/data.log
# End of script
```

Что в файле:

```
<Fri 10 Nov 21:53:23 GMT 2017><enp2s0><4053647813><103337400>
<Fri 10 Nov 21:53:23 GMT 2017><tap0><26173605><2178109097>
<Fri 10 Nov 21:53:21 GMT 2017><enp2s0><4053647182><103336765>
<Fri 10 Nov 21:53:21 GMT 2017><tap0><26173605><2178109045>
<Fri 10 Nov 21:53:19 GMT 2017><enp2s0><4053647182><103336765>
<Fri 10 Nov 21:53:19 GMT 2017><tap0><26173605><2178108993>
<Fri 10 Nov 21:53:17 GMT 2017><enp2s0><4053646958><103336409>
<Fri 10 Nov 21:53:17 GMT 2017><tap0><26173605><2178108941>
<Fri 10 Nov 21:50:54 GMT 2017><enp2s0><103208421><4052071629>
<Fri 10 Nov 21:50:54 GMT 2017><tap0><2178105197><26173605>
```

Добавьте его в cron с желаемым интервалом.

Answer (score 1):

Можно готовой утилитой воспользоваться, чтобы следить за сетевым трафиком. [vnstat](http://humdi.net/vnstat/):

```
$ vnstat -m

eth1  /  monthly

  month         rx      |      tx      |    total     |   avg. rate
------------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------
 Nov '08      74.94 GiB |    96.48 GiB |   171.42 GiB |  554.76 kbit/s
 Dec '08     279.32 GiB |   276.05 GiB |   555.37 GiB |    1.74 Mbit/s
 Jan '09     324.34 GiB |   413.38 GiB |   737.72 GiB |    2.31 Mbit/s
 Feb '09     273.73 GiB |   362.49 GiB |   636.22 GiB |    2.21 Mbit/s
 Mar '09     353.50 GiB |   270.03 GiB |   623.53 GiB |    1.95 Mbit/s
 Apr '09     361.74 GiB |   365.01 GiB |   726.74 GiB |    2.35 Mbit/s
 May '09     345.62 GiB |   440.43 GiB |   786.05 GiB |    2.46 Mbit/s
 Jun '09     758.45 GiB |   359.30 GiB |     1.09 TiB |    3.62 Mbit/s
 Jul '09     609.40 GiB |   282.21 GiB |   891.61 GiB |    2.79 Mbit/s
 Aug '09      17.13 GiB |    10.50 GiB |    27.63 GiB |    2.81 Mbit/s
------------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------
estimated    556.15 GiB |   340.85 GiB |   897.00 GiB |
```

[Разные форматы вывода](http://humdi.net/vnstat/cgidemo/) поддерживаются.